# Excel lookup value not on same row

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

What i`m looking for is that the data will be filled automatically from data table by lookup value in not same row.

See the picture

[image]

or xls example https://dropmefiles.com/BDlHe

1st table lookup value is RUCA22 - I need to fill the cell to June from another table.

1. So formula should look to data table
2. Understand the lookup value (the difficulty that the value is not in
   the same row with figure.It is up 1 row from it)
3. Go to column Jun-15
4. And return the figure 100% to the cell in the 1st table.

Comment: This is very difficult to understand. I added your picture, but I still don't get it.

Comment: Dear Raystafarian,

Comment: Dear Raystafarian, thank u a lot for adding the picture. It is hard to explain the thoughts.  Possibly the xls file will help understannd the request more detailed?! The aim is to get the number of persentage from another table.  For ex: excel looks for RUCA22(lookup value) in next table with datas. Looks for figure in Jun cell and return the number.  If the lookup value was in same row with datas it will be easier to get number. But the name (for ex RUCA22) is 1 row above. So VLOOKUP function will return only the name of month - Jun< but I need data below the months name (ex:100%)

Comment: i tried offset with vlookup to give the number a row below but it didnt work

Comment: Hi all,  Found decision myself, Putting the formula, if any interests or xls. required pls let me know.  OFFSET(INDEX();MATCH(); MATCH();0));1;0)  So function first looks for value in row, then looks for requested value in column, then Index gives number in position. Because we need data the row below i used offset formula with 1 row down, Finally instead Jun I got 100%. Function gave the possibility to lookup the value in n-rows down or up from it position

Comment: Be sure to post an answer if you've solved your question